# What is it called in linguistics when you change a word from one part of speech to another?

Tags: terminology

So, what is it called when, for instance, the following happens:

> mad(noun) > madly (adv) > madlyness (noun)

Comment: See also: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/21355/do-other-languages-than-english-have-verbals-too

Answer (score 10):

First: We say "part of speech", not "word of speech".

Second: "madlyness" is not an English word.

Third: The term you are looking for is "derivation".

Comment: +1 Second is quite right: it should be *madliness*. "He spoke with such madliness that he was reduced to incoherence."

Comment: The correct English word is "madness".

Comment: Not divination, derivation.

Comment: @user5309 your last comment may be considered rude. Consider deleting and re-writing it without any personal insults. This is not a chat room.

Comment: Also "mad" is not a noun. It's an adjective. You could use another example like `man(noun) > manly (adj) > manliness (noun)`

Answer (score -5):

You cannot 'change' a word from one part of speech to another. The words already exist or they don't. (You can form a new noun from a verb, but you are not 'changing' it to a noun.) A noun is a noun and cannot be a verb. Some words exist as several parts of speech ('set', 'run', 'form', 'hold', etc.), though usually with somewhat different meanings.

Consider the shifts in meaning of 'house' in 'house wine', 'the part of the car that houses the engine', and 'this is my house'.

Others have separate spellings for noun, adjective, and verb forms ('beauty', 'beautiful', 'beautify'). As I said above, you can use some words as nouns or verbs, but you are not 'changing' them to do so. You do not have the authority to do this if it has not already occurred long ago. 'Car' for instance is a noun, not a verb, and cannot be used as one. 'To sign' the verb and 'sign' the noun are different words, just like 'beauty', 'beautiful', 'beautify'; one is not 'changed' into the other.

Comment: This is incorrect. Have a look at [WP on zero-derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation)).

Comment: A rose is a rose but those are concrete so it doesn't imply that a noun is a noun at all since that's an arbitrary abstract concept about which we can have multiple conflicting theories and no access to any "one right answer" designed by any creator deities.

Answer (score -6):

What the poster is describing is called "Inflection". Changing the basic form of the word, typically by adding a suffix, to express a function such as tense, quantity, gender. Examples: the adjective 'mad' is *inflected* to the adverb 'madly', nouns are *inflected* in the plural, verbs are *inflected* in the various tenses.

'Inflection' also means the WAY you say things, the highs and lows of your voice, or the stress patterns (anger, asking a question, joking,) but for that sort of thing I would go with "intonation".

Comment: This isn't inflection. Inflection for tense, quantity or gender doesn't change the word's part of speech. This does.

Comment: It's not inflection?? With all respect WavesWashSands the poster gave a discription, asked if there's a name for it, and inflection is indeed the correct terminology. Thanks to the internet I can quickly look at several dictionaries:

Comment: With all due respect, this is definitely not inflection in the sense that linguists use it. Perhaps philological or pedagogical circles use inflection that way, I don't know; such uses would be reflected in definitions in descriptive dictionaries. The point is, in linguistics, the term *inflection* is not used for morphological processes that change the POS - the word *derivation* is used instead, as fdb has explaiend above. There are a lot of linguistic terms whose definitions linguists can't agree on (like 'pronoun' or 'adjunct'), but this isn't one of them.

Comment: COLLINS = In grammar, an inflection is a change in the form of a word that shows its grammatical function, for example a change that makes a noun plural or makes a verb into the past tense. MERRIAM WEBSTER = a :  the change of form that words undergo to mark such distinctions as those of case, gender, number, tense, person, mood, or voice
b :  a form, suffix, or element involved in such variation. //// Please explain how the original poster's discription is not inflection.

Comment: It's me again, I wanted my 2 replies (limited characters) to follow each other but air was having a dickens of a time trying to edit. Sorry that my second reply came after your reply to me

Comment: WavesWashSands -- I'm trying to figure out your logic here. I think what's happening is you're perhaps looking at the word inflection through historical/didactic eyes? Language evolves and the average person doesn't care about philological this and pedagogical that. Thank you for the talk but I'm standing by "inflection" to the death.

Comment: Um, quite the opposite - what I meant was that perhaps philologists and language teachers use the word 'inflection' differently. Such a usage would be reflected in dictionaries, but it doesn't mean it's correct *in linguistics*. This is a linguistics site, so the use of terminology should be consistent with *what linguists use*. Current linguistic nomenclature does not use the word *inflection* for what the OP described.

Comment: The dictionary definition you cited isn't consistent with the use of *inflection* with POS-changing morphology. It was a bit unclear - 'grammatical category' would have been better than 'grammatical function', which is usually synonymous with 'grammatical relation' in linguistics; however, using the term 'grammatical category' would render the definition inaccessible to non-linguists, which is probably why they decided against it. Still, none of the distinctions they cite as examples change the part of speech of words, whereas the OP is describing a process that does.

Comment: Or perhaps an analogy will be more apt: It is acceptable in everyday speech to call 50kg a 'weight', but it wouldn't be acceptable to do so on the Physics.SE site.

Comment: WWS ok I get what you're saying. I see an earlier post I made isn't there.  Navigating here is frustrating. This is my first and last day here, I've had it.                                                                                     Thanks again WWS

Comment: This is a dead thread, but for those finding it anew, if you read those definitions carefully, Nick Vavas is 100% wrong. Inflection can change the "case, gender, number, tense, person, mood, or voice", but in none of those does it say "part of speech," because that's separate.